# User Device Identification

Tags: algorithm, networking, browser

I am working on a OTT platform website which has a user's total device loggedin limitation. Each time the user is visiting the website I need to get the user's device info. How can i uniquely identify each new device a specific user is using to log in? Is there any way which uniquely help in identifying a new device?

I already tried using IP address, Cookies and user-agent. But these are not reliable as it can be changed an tampered easily.

Comment: Fingerprinting? IP is actually pretty reliable if you accept that it can be impossible to tell whether a user in their own home has several identical devices and just allows them, while also blocking known VPN and proxy IPs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.